# How do operators work in Java and why does this method return null?

Tags: java, if-statement, null, operators

i am studying computer science and my homework was finding the next day.

The method `getNextDay()` returns null and doesn't go through my `If` statements.

Here are the two classes that are used:

```
public class NextDay {

           public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
              Date dateObj = new Date(30, 3, 2016);
              System.out.println("Altes Datum: " + dateObj.gibTag() + "." + dateObj.gibMonat() + "." + dateObj.gibJahr() + ".");
              System.out.println("Der naechste Tag ist der " + dateObj.getNextDay().toString() + ".");
           }
}



public class Date {
    int tag;
    int monat;
    int jahr;

    public Date(int tag, int monat, int jahr){
        this.tag = tag;
        this.monat = monat;
        this.jahr = jahr;
    }

    public Date getNextDay() throws Exception{  

        if(monat == 2){
        // wenn Februar 29 Tage hat.
        if(jahr % 4 == 0 | jahr % 400 == 0){
            if(tag > 0 & tag < 29){
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);  
            }
            else if(tag == 29 & monat == 2){
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            }else{
                throw new Exception("Im Februar können Sie nur bis 28 schreiben!");
            }   
        }
        // wenn Februar 28 Tage hat.
        if(jahr % 4 != 0 | jahr % 100 != 0 & monat == 2){
            if(tag > 0 & tag < 28){
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);  
            }else if(tag == 28 & monat == 2){
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            }           
            else{
                throw new Exception("Im Februar können Sie nur bis 28 schreiben!");
            }   
        }
        }


        if(monat != 2 & monat == 1 & monat == 3 & monat == 5 & monat == 7 & monat == 8 & monat == 10 & monat == 12 ){
        if(tag <= 31 & monat <= 12 & jahr > 0){
            if(tag < 31){
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);  
            }
            else if(tag == 31 & monat < 12){
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            }
            else if(monat == 12){
                if(tag == 31 & monat == 12){
                    return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat - monat + 1, jahr + 1);
                }else{
                    return new Date(tag, monat, jahr + 1);
                }
            }

        }
            else{
                throw new Exception("Sie haben ein ungültiges Datum eingegeben!");
            }

        }


        if(monat != 2 & monat == 4 & monat == 6 & monat == 9 & monat == 11){
            if(tag <= 30 & monat <= 12 & jahr > 0){
                if(tag < 30){
                    return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);  
                }
                else if(tag == 30 & monat < 12){
                    return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
                }
                else if(monat == 12){
                    if(tag == 31 & monat == 12){
                        return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat - monat + 1, jahr + 1);
                    }else{
                        return new Date(tag, monat, jahr + 1);
                    }
                }

            }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("Sie haben ein ungültiges Datum eingegeben!");
                }

            }
        return null;


    }



    public int gibTag(){
        return tag;
    }

    public int gibMonat(){
        return monat;
    }

    public int gibJahr(){
        return jahr;
    }       


    public String toString(){
        return this.tag + "." + this.monat + "." + this.jahr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend translating your code to English before posting it. So it is easier for people to understand it and help you.

Comment: one simple reason could be , no condition block get executed so eventually you get null in return hence null pointer plus don't confuse your naming convention with API (Date is an API)

Comment: I think he not need to convert codes to English. Because only three tag used in code block. Tag = Day, Monat = Month, Jahre=Year and gibJahr etc. means of gib = get. There is no reason to translate.

Comment: When would the month be 1 and 3 and 5 and 7 and 8 and 10 and 12 at the same time?

Comment: @tkausl I believe that this question was just not asked properly and now that it has been edited. You should cast a vote to re - open it. Unfortunately I do not have the necessary 3000 reputation to cast a vote.

Comment: @PeterLawrey OP made a mistake and was using bit wise operators instead of conditional operators. Just check my answer below.

Comment: @nickzoum the problem was using AND instead of OR, and whether the OP used bit-wise or logical operators doesn't matter, reopened.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The problem was using bit wise operators when || was what was needed. The bit wise operator "|" would have probably also worked, and that is a mistake but I think the main error is using the wrong kind of operators. Why confuse a person who is new to programming with things that he does not yet need to know.

Comment: @nickzoum yes, wrong operator but the first line of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125235/discussion-between-nick-zoum-and-peter-lawrey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using wrong [bit-wise operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) (`&`). Instead you should you use this conditional operator `||`.

As a result in the `getNextDay()` method you none of the if statements are met and therefore the only line of code that is being read is `return null;`

And when you try to call a method on an object that is `null` then you get `NullPointerException`.

As a start i would recommend changing the `getNextDay()` method to:

```
public Date getNextDay() throws Exception {
    if (monat == 2) {
        // wenn Februar 29 Tage hat.
        if (jahr % 4 == 0 || jahr % 400 == 0) {
            if (tag > 0 & tag < 29) {
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);
            } else if (tag == 29 & monat == 2) {
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Im Februar können Sie nur bis 28 schreiben!");
            }
        }
        // wenn Februar 28 Tage hat.
        if (jahr % 4 != 0 || jahr % 100 != 0 && monat == 2) {
            if (tag > 0 & tag < 28) {
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);
            } else if (tag == 28 & monat == 2) {
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Im Februar können Sie nur bis 28 schreiben!");
            }
        }
    } else if (monat == 1 || monat == 3 || monat == 5 || monat == 7 || monat == 8 || monat == 10 || monat == 12) {
        if (tag <= 31 & monat <= 12 & jahr > 0) {
            if (tag < 31) {
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);
            } else if (tag == 31 & monat < 12) {
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            } else if (monat == 12) {
                if (tag == 31 & monat == 12) {
                    return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat - monat + 1, jahr + 1);
                } else {
                    return new Date(tag, monat, jahr + 1);
                }
            }

        } else {
            throw new Exception("Sie haben ein ungültiges Datum eingegeben!");
        }

    } else if (monat == 4 || monat == 6 || monat == 9 || monat == 11) {
        if (tag <= 30 & monat <= 12 & jahr > 0) {
            if (tag < 30) {
                return new Date(tag + 1, monat, jahr);
            } else if (tag == 30 & monat < 12) {
                return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat + 1, jahr);
            } else if (monat == 12) {
                if (tag == 31 & monat == 12) {
                    return new Date(tag - tag + 1, monat - monat + 1, jahr + 1);
                } else {
                    return new Date(tag, monat, jahr + 1);
                }
            }

        } else {
            throw new Exception("Sie haben ein ungültiges Datum eingegeben!");
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

See how the if statements are now different. Try it for yourself.

Comment: thank you very much :) i get it now i used all the time & but you did it with ||.

Comment: @meert  I think you also have a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @meert And I thank you too. Since you have now joined the stack overflow community, I would recommend going through this page http://stackoverflow.com/tour (You will also get a badge)

Comment: You should note that using logical operators vs bitwise made no difference in this case.